# How can I write a function in objective - c convert to 6 digit integer to 4 byte Hexadecimal value?

Tags: objective-c

How can I convert a integer 6 digit number such as "1234674" to a hexadecimal 4 byte NSData in  Objective-C ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

data are bytes, and bytes are bits not hex, hex it's just a way to interpret data. An int in ARM is 32 bit (you can use int32_t or sizeof)

you can do

```
int x = 1234674;
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&x length:sizeof(int)]
```

and then if you want to print out that data as hex:

```
char c[4] = [myData bytes];
NSLog("%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X%02%02X%02",c[0],c[1],c[2],c[3]]);
```

If you just want to print out or convert to a hex string, you can use a char pointer like this:

```
char *c = &x;
NSString *hexStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"%02X%02%02X%02", *c, *(c+1), *(c+2), *(c+3)];
```

i didn't try to code, but should be working and in case i hope you got the idea

Comment: This is the part of our code that sends passkey:

#define HSL_PRIVATE_SERVICE_UUID 0xFF20
#define HSL_PRIVATE_NEW_PASSKEY_UUID 0xFF35
unsigned int newPassKey = [_confirmNewPassKey.text intValue];
NSLog(@"newPasskey %d", newPassKey);
NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytes:&newPassKey length:sizeof(unsigned int)];
[_t writeValue:HSL_PRIVATE_SERVICE_UUID characteristicUUID:HSL_PRIVATE_NEW_PASSKEY_UUID p:_peripheral data:d];

Comment: I did an air capture comparing BTOOL versus iPhone passkey writes.
BTOOL wrote 0x40e201
iPhone wrote 0x0001e240

Not sure what is going on and how to fix it in the app so that the result matches what the Bluetooth device is expecting . I would like the result to be same as BTOOL one.